# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

В консоли отладчика при попытке загрузить страницу появляется сообщение:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

с ссылкой на строку в scripts.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {...
```

Подключенные скрипты:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/messi.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js' </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/camera.min.js'></script>
```

В итоге скрипты у меня не работают. Что значит данное сообщение и как правильно подключить скрипты?

Comment: Либо путь для скриптов неверный, либо jquery.min.js отсутствует

Comment: Немного неправильно оформил вопрос, исправил. Самая первая строка в scripts.js: (function($) {... Все скрипты существуют и открываются в браузере

Comment: jquery не подключен

Comment: @messenja Проверьте ещё раз путь к `jquery` и скиньте, пожалуйста, весь код файла.

Comment: @Максим скинул на пастебин [ссылка]https://pastebin.com/nzDbeuBN jquery.min.js и scripts.js открываются в браузере

Comment: @messenja Попробуйте подключить `jquery` с интернета(проверьте будет ли тоже самое), я думаю, тут дело в неправильно указанном пути.

Comment: @Максим я открыл исходный код страницы в браузере, кликнул на строке, где подключается jquery.min.js и он открылся, т.е. скрипт виден.

Comment: @messenja, Вы решили свою проблему? Добавьте ответ.

Answer (score 1):

"Самая первая строка в scripts.js: `(function($) {...`" - а последняя?

То, что Вы туда подаете в качестве параметра, не является функцией `jQuery`.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте разместить теги "script" с подключением(-ями) jquery перед тегами "script", которые подключают файлы, где используется jquery. То есть, теги с файлами "scripts.js" и "messi.js" подключите последними.